# Which is the proper way get store log in talend ETL

Tags: etl, talend

I am new for Talend ETL. So which is the proper way to store talend logs when its running in automate.

1. Job running time 

2. Error in-case if Job return error

3. Number of rows

Comment: Probably duplicate with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41878998/common-logging-in-talend/41881659

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Talend Open Studio **tStatCatcher** components listens to components that have the tStatCatcher Statistics option set to true, and writes statistics information to the defined output. tStatCatcher also listens for the start and end of a Job's execution.

End of the job's execution, pass the logs from `tStatCatcher` to database